# Converting bitmap to grayscale

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing

I have a WinForm application, and I want to load a Bitmap(.bmp) in a picturebox directly converted to grayscale. I have the code on how to load and filter the image, and I have also the code for converting the image...but I don't know how to connect these into a working program

```
private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    OpenFileDialog fDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    fDialog.Filter = "Bitmaps |*.bmp| GIFs |*.gif| JPEGs |*.jpg;*.jpeg| TIFs |*.tif";
    fDialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\\";
    if (fDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        pcbImage.Image = Image.FromFile(fDialog.FileName);
        pcbImage.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should explain a little further and give some examples of what you got and what you want. I read your question three times and I'm not sure what you want to say.. "like this". like what?

Comment: Is this a WinForms application, ASP.NET?  MVC or Forms?  There is notwhere near enough info in this question to know where to start.

Comment: Unsure about closing... he certainly looked a bit confused (it's understandable as he's new here) but at least part of the question is clear, while there could be a duplicate somewhere. Just my opinion... Should we encourage this guy to edit the question and improve it? (Can he actually edit a closed question?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question shows you are pretty confused about images and .NET Framework.

With my answer, I won't provide you with code, as it takes a little extra time, but I want to help you with my advices. Here is the algorithm, coding will be up to you.

First of all, get the image as RGB using the `Image` class. Once you have loaded the image you have a structure made of pixels, each one having the three components `R`, `G` and `B`. Please don't be offended if I start from the very basics, but I have no idea about your actual level of experience.

You now have to generate a new image **with the same widht and height** of the original image. A grayscale image is characterized by having `R==G==B`, which means the new image must have all 3 values the same for each pixel.

In order to get the value, you have quite a few options: a common option (mostly wrong) is to perform arithmetic mean, ie. `C = (R+G+B)/3` (you have to asssign it thrice, once for each component). I'll tell you later why this choice is wrong but commonly accepted.

Here is the **pseudo-code** that works for you

```
Image old;
old = Image.Load("file.bmp"); //I don't currently have MSDN at hand, nor I remember how to load the bitmap
Image new = new Image{ Width = old.Width; Height = old.Height };
for (i=0; i<old.Width-1; i++)
    for (j=0; j<old.Height; j++)
    {
        Color p = old[i,j];
        byte gray = (p.R+p.G+p.B)/3;
        new[i,j] = new Color(gray,gray,gray);
    }
 }
 pictureBox.Image = new;
```

Again notice: this code resembles pseudo-code, and I didn't actually test it.

## Why is arithmetical mean wrong?

(the most interesting part of the question, from the scientific point)

Grayscale images are based on the concept of **luminance**, which is the power of the light reflected by an object and impressed on a luminance sensor (ie. a grayscale camera). Colour natural light is made up of electro-magnetic waves with a wide spectrum, but common sensors are triggered only by frequencies in **red**, **green** and **blue** spectrums. The human eye, also, *is more sensitive to green colour rather than others* (I had a diagram that shows human eye response to light at different frequencies).

**This means** that assuming the three light's components provide **equal** contribute to luminance is wrong, as when you show a viewer two lamps of the same power, one filtered green and one filtered blue, the observer will tell you that the green is brighter.

There is a conversion table (I update the post later if I find it) that shows how to perform a **weighted** mean with proper coefficients to deal with this phenomenon. Also, it has been found that images converted through this table look more *realistic* than other images converted with regular mean.

[Follow-up] I just found [this article](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-convert-a-color-image-to-grayscale) with working code samples

## Edit

Now that you have shown a good question (and told that you **have the conversion code**) let me help you. If you posted your conversion code, it would have been more helpful. You have to separately **load** your image from disk, **edit** it and **bind** to the PictureBox.

Supposing you have a `private Image ConvertToGrayscale(Image source);`, here is the code that works for you:

```
private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    OpenFileDialog fDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    fDialog.Filter = "Bitmaps |*.bmp| GIFs |*.gif| JPEGs |*.jpg;*.jpeg| TIFs |*.tif";
    fDialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\\";
    if (fDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Image old = Image.FromFile(fDialog.FileName);
        pcbImage.Image = ConvertToGrayscale(old);
        pcbImage.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're assuming "bitmap" means a .bmp file and not a monochrome one-bit-per-pixel bitmap. Impossible to tell from the question.

Comment: Not exactly .bmp. Even JPEG gets decompressed to a *matrix* format (I volountarily changed the *bitmap* word). I just assume he's using System.Drawing

Comment: Thank you for your answers...and yes I am using System.Drawing...

Comment: Are you still able to edit your question to a more appropriate format? We will reopen it gladly if you reformulate the question answering some of the other guys' comments

Comment: I have a WinForm application, and I want to load a Bitmap(.bmp) in a picturebox directly converted to grayscale. I have the code on how to load and filter the image, and I have also the code for converting the image...but I don't know how to connect these into a working program

Comment: private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog fDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

            fDialog.Filter =
                "Bitmaps |*.bmp| GIFs |*.gif| JPEGs |*.jpg;*.jpeg| TIFs |*.tif";

            fDialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\\";
            if (fDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                pcbImage.Image = Image.FromFile(fDialog.FileName);
                pcbImage.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            }

        }

Comment: Thank you...this really helped...now it's working properly...

Comment: I did this from your example:                                     if (fDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Bitmap old = Bitmap.FromFile(fDialog.FileName);
                pcbImage.Image = ConvertToGrayscale(old);
                pcbImage.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            }            and I get this error: " Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Image' to 'System.Drawing.Bitmap'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
"

Comment: I am using the first example for convertion from that tutorial you gave to me...

Comment: got it...now it's working again:D